# connecting tornadio2 and mysql

Tags: python, comet, tornado

has anyone managed to connect tornadio2 to mysql to push/pull messages.

what is the best way to do this? or if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if MySQL is very good choice - you will have to poll MySQL table and it is quite inefficient.

However, if you want to go MySQL route, there's no asynchronous driver for the MySQL as far as I'm aware.

So, you can do it this way:

1. Create thread which will poll database for more data
2. If something found - transfer control to IOLoop thread with IOLoop.add_callback (see more info here - https://github.com/facebook/tornado/wiki/Threading-and-concurrency)
3. In main thread process received data and send it through TornadIO2 connections

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If mysql is a bad choice to use, what would be a better method to store the user messages. These messages will be stored for quite a long time so there would be a large backlog.

Comment: If it is persistent data storage, you can try PostgreSQL - there's asynchronous driver for Tornado and you can grab last N messages and send them to the user. If it is message queue that user should receive while he's connected - use Redis/AMQP (RabbitMQ, etc). In most of the cases Redis would work even with large data amounts. Also, you can mix two: store flag "more data for user A available" in redis and store data in the database.